# How to pass a pointer from Rust to an external WASM module function, such that it can modify that value?

Tags: html, rust, memory, module, webassembly

I am trying to allow user to select a file .wasm in HTML page, then pass a function from that module into already loaded Rust wasm module. After that I want to call that function and pass pointers, such that it can modify values from inside my Rust module.

However what I tried, which normally works when dynamically loading libraries, doesn't work here.

I'd expect it to modify the `val` variable. But nothing changes.

**External module loaded by user**

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn modify(val: *mut u8) {
    let val = unsafe { &mut *val };
    *val = 5;
}
```

**Rust module calling function from external module**

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn call_modify(modify: Function) {
    let mut val = 7u8;
    let val_ptr = &mut val as *mut u8;

    console_log!("before {val}");

    modify.call1(&JsValue::NULL, &JsValue::from(val_ptr)).unwrap();

    console_log!("after {val}");
}
```

**Index.html allowing user to select external module, and then passes function to my Rust module**

```html
button id="load-wasm-file-btn">Load Wasm File</button>
    <input type="file" id="wasm-file-input" accept=".js" style="display: none;" />
    <button id="load-wasm-data-btn">Load Wasm Data</button>
    <input type="file" id="wasm-data-input" accept=".wasm" style="display: none;" />
    <script type="module">
        import init, {call_modify} from "./pkg/dynamic_wasm_loading.js";
        await init();

        var wasm_url;

        document.getElementById("load-wasm-data-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
            document.getElementById("wasm-data-input").click();
        });

        document.getElementById("wasm-data-input").addEventListener("change", async (e) => {
            const file = e.target.files[0];

            wasm_url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        });

        document.getElementById("load-wasm-file-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
            document.getElementById("wasm-file-input").click();
        });

        document.getElementById("wasm-file-input").addEventListener("change", async (e) => {
            // load javascript file and execute function inside it called 'execute'

            const file = e.target.files[0];

            // Create a URL from the file object
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

            // Dynamically import the module
            import(fileURL).then(async (module) => {
            // Set the computer_func to the module's 'execute' function
                console.log(wasm_url);
                console.log("initializing...");
                console.log(module);

                await module.default(wasm_url);
                console.log("initialized");
                console.log(module.modify);
                call_modify(module.modify);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error importing module:', error);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't think sharing memory between WASM modules is generally possible at the moment.

Comment: Does that imply that there is no way to pass a mutable reference whatsoever?

Comment: One option how two wasm modules can communicate between each themselves would be to pass a js callback to one module and from that callback call a function in the other module.